# When set Visual Studio as external editor tool, Unity will freeze (macbook version)

Tags: unity, visual-studio

So I want to link visual studio and Unity, but if I set vs as the external editor tool and open a script, after I open a script for around 1 minute, Unity will freeze and I can't do anything but quit the application. 
Also, if I set vs as external editor tool and double click on a script, visual studio won't automatically open the script, and I need to manually navigate to the script in vs to open up the script. 
Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Unity changed how it links with editors quite a bit in the last couple years. Are you up to date on your VS and unity versions? Also check package manager and look at the same package. Make sure that’s up to date too

Comment: Everything is up to date, everything is on the newest version already

Comment: This sounds like a bug to report to the Unity development team.